# Term wise differention

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, power-series

Consider $S(x) = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}} x^k k^2$.

(a) Find an explicit formula for $S(x)$ on the interval $-1<x<1$ by repeated termwise differentiation of a geometric series. Be sure to justify.

(b) Use the above result to evaluate $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}} \frac{k^2}{3^k}$.

Hint: $x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} x^k + x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^k$

For (a) can I say that $S(x) = x^2\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} x^k + x\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^k$. I am able to take the derivative termwise since I know that it converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$ and it converges for some $x_0 \in (-1,1). $

Comment: Start with $G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ which has a radius of convergence of 1, so you can go wild with differentiation for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the radius of convergence of $G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ is 1, we can differentiate term-wise when $|x| <1$. Furthermore, since $|x|<1$, we can sum the
geometric series explicitly to get
$G(x) = {1 \over 1-x}$.

$G'(x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^{k} = {1 \over (1-x)^2}$.

We see from this that $H(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k} = G'(x)-G(x) = { x \over (1-x)^2}$.

Repeating the process gives
$H'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2x^{k-1}  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^2x^{k} = {1+x \over (1-x)^3 }$.

Since $(k+1)^2 = k^2+2k+1$, we get
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^{k} = H'(x)-2H(x)-G(x) = { x(x+1) \over (1-x)^3 }$.

Part (b) should be straightforward with the appropriate choice of $x$.

Comment: Should the last step be $H'(x)+2H(x)+G(x)$?

Comment: No, you want $k^2x^k=(k+1)^2x^k-2kx^k-x^k$.